# How do I connect two tables to see if a value exist in any of the two

Tags: php, mysql

I having problems connecting the below query together so that It works more efficient.Can someone please tell me how I can connect these two queries so that it is only one?

```
$rs_duplicate = mysql_query("select count(*) as total 
                             from advertisers_account
                             where user_email='$user_email' ") or die(mysql_error());

list($total) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_duplicate);

    }

$rs_duplicate_pub = mysql_query("select count(*) as total 
                                 from publishers_account
                                 where user_email='$user_email' ") or die(mysql_error());

list($totalpub) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_duplicate_pub);


if ($totalpub ||  $total  > 0)
{
    echo "Not Available  ";

} else {

    echo "Available";
}
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I'm also not sure about receiving the resultset into `list($total)`. I believe you should use `$total` only.

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION:

```
SELECT 'advertisers' AS which, count(*) AS total
FROM advertisers_account
WHERE user_email = '$user_email'
UNION
SELECT 'publishers' AS which, count(*) AS total
FROM publishers_account
WHERE user_email = '$user_email'
```

This query will return two rows, you can use the `which` column to tell whether it's advertisers or publishers.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it. you need to use joins, but you should make sure to not let any variables in the query be directly from an outside user like from a form submit. That will open you up to SQL Injection. Use Prepared Statements instead.

```
select count(*) as total from publishers_account INNER JOIN advertisers_account ON advertisers_account.user_email = publishers_account.user_email WHERE user_email='$user_email'
```

Answer (score 1):

in response to: 
Can someone please tell me how I can connect these two queries so that it is only one?

Why not:

```
Select 
(select count(*) as total from advertisers_account where user_email='$user_email') +
(select count(*) as total from publishers_account where user_email='$user_email') as sumofCount
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(advertisers_account.id)
FROM publishers_account
LEFT JOIN advertisers_account ON publisher_account.email = advertisers_account.email
WHERE publisher_account.email = '$user_email';
```

If the count is greater than zero, then the email exists in both tables at least once. If it exists only in the left table (publishers), then the counter would be zero. If it doesn't exist at all in the left table, then you'll get no rows at all, even if it does exist in the right table (advertisers)